# Micrometer Tracing traceId not passing into downstream

Tags: spring, spring-micrometer

Let's say I have two Microservice. When trying to use Micrometer, traceId was not traversing to the next microservice.

I am providing code of cart service which will call product service.

The traceId which gets printed in cart and product service are different.

Not able to understand the issue.

```
server.port=8081
spring.application.name=product_catalog
logging.level.org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet=TRACE
management.tracing.sampling.probability=1.0
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
logging.pattern.level=%5p [${spring.application.name:},%X{traceId:-},%X{spanId:-}]



import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@RestController
public class ShoppingCartService {

@Autowired
RestTemplate restTemplate;
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ShoppingCartService.class);

@GetMapping("/cart")
public String addItem() {
    logger.info("add item - process started");
    final Product itemProduct = 
restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8081/product",
            Product.class);
    System.out.println("itemProduct" + itemProduct);
    return "ok";
    }
}






     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Hi .. I am facing the same problem and did you resolve this issue ? if yes please share your findings

Answer (score 6):

After migrating to Spring Boot 3, you need to add an interceptor to RestTemplate.

This worked for me.

Add the library to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.zipkin.brave</groupId>
    <artifactId>brave-instrumentation-spring-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Add TracingClientHttpRequestInterceptor to RestTemplate

```
import brave.Tracing;
import brave.http.HttpTracing;
import brave.spring.web.TracingClientHttpRequestInterceptor;
```

---

```
@Bean
public HttpTracing create(Tracing tracing) {
    return HttpTracing
        .newBuilder(tracing)
        .build();
}

@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(HttpTracing httpTracing) {
    return new RestTemplateBuilder()           
            .interceptors(TracingClientHttpRequestInterceptor.create(httpTracing))
        .build();
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: It works like magic!

Comment: Thank you so much. We were struggling to solve this issue from last week.

Comment: One more issue I am facing, during tracing of any particular trace, it is also showing securityFilterChain spans as well. Do we have any way to hide those spans.